# How to use PictureBox in XNA?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, bitmap, xna, webcam

I am trying to use webcam in XNA. I have created the webcam on Windows Form Successfully. Now i want to use the same code in XNA. In Windows Form i am using pictureBox to show the Webcam Video. I want to use the pictureBox in XNA as well.

I have imported `System.Drawing` Library and using it as `using Bitmap = System.Drawing.Bitmap;`

I am using AForge Framework. Following is my code that i had written in Windows Form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;
    private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideo;

    string DeviceName;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

        foreach (FilterInfo VideoCaptureDevice in VideoCaptureDevices)
        {
           DeviceName= VideoCaptureDevice.Name;
        }

        FinalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(VideoCaptureDevices[0].MonikerString);
        FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
        FinalVideo.Start();
       // MessageBox.Show(DeviceName);

    }

    void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pictureBox1.Image = image;

    }
```

-

I have written almost the same code in XNA, and its successfully showing me the CAMERA name. Kindly tell me how can i use picture Box or any other way to Display the Webcam video

**XNA-CODE**

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    //WebCamVideo - Start

    VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

    foreach (FilterInfo VideoCaptureDevice in VideoCaptureDevices)
    {
        DeviceName = VideoCaptureDevice.Name;
    }


    myfont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("myfont");

    FinalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(VideoCaptureDevices[0].MonikerString);
    FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
    FinalVideo.Start();

    //WebCamVideo- End 
}

void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    //In Forms I used Picuture Box here to Display the Webcam video
}
```

Comment: here is some example: http://bettercoderwannabe.blogspot.com/2012/09/xna-and-webcam-stream-as-background.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function for converting a Bitmap to a Texture2D.

```
Texture2D BitmapToTexture(Bitmap bmap)
{
    Mircosoft.Xna.Framework.Color[] colors = new Color[bmap.Width * bmap.Height];
    for (int x = 0; x < bmap.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bmap.Height; y++)
        {
            int index = x + y * bmap.Width;
            System.Color color = bmap.GetPixel(x, y);
            Vector4 colorVector =
                new Vector4((float)color.R / 255f,
                            (float)color.G / 255f,
                            (float)color.B / 255f, 1);
            colors[index] = Color.FromNonPremultiplied(colorVector);
        }
    }

    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, bmap.Width, bmap.Height);
    texture.SetData<Color>(colors);
    return texture;
}
```